# Wortfamilien, die immer noch im Deutschen produktiv sind, aber nicht im Englischen?

Tags: etymology, reference-request

Mir ist neulich aufgefallen, dass die Wörter "forlorn" (von Englisch) und "verloren" nicht nur ähnlich klingen, sondern wahrscheinlich auch gemeinsame Wurzeln besitzen. Hierfür habe ich auch Belege gefunden: [(1)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=forlorn) [(2)](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/forlorn#Etymology).

Ich habe diese Verbindung lange Zeit nicht gesehen, weil die Wurzel für "forlorn", d.h. "forlese", ganz aus dem Wortschatz verschwunden ist, und deshalb keine neue Wörter werden von ihm produziert. Im Gegensatz dazu wird neue Wörter aus "verloren" bis heute erzeugt.

**Frage:** Kennt jemand weitere Quellen, in denen noch weitere solche Beispiele (d.h. nur zwischen dem Deutschen und dem Englischen) diskutiert werden?

Weitere Beispiele wären z. B. "hin" und "thither", "her" und "hither", "wofür" (im Sinne von warum) und "wherefore", "du/Sie" und "thou/thee", usw.

Comment: widdershins/widersinnig fällt mir in diesem Zusammenhang als weiteres nettes Beispiel ein. Quellen für eine allgemeine Erörterung kenne ich aber keine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Für diese spezifische Fragestellung (Wörter, die im Deutschen noch verwendet werden, im Englischen aber nicht mehr) sind mir keine Quellen bekannt.

Allgemein kann man sich aber Wortlisten von etymologisch verwandten Wörtern im Deutschen und Englischen angucken und darüber Worte, wie du sie suchst, aufspüren. Etymologisch verwandte Wörter in verschiedenen Sprachen bezeichnet man faschsprachlich auch als *Kognaten* bzw. engl. *cognates*. Die Internetsuche nach "cognate english german" führt einen schnell zu vielen verschiedenen Wortlisten, als Einstieg nicht schlecht ist vielleicht diese hier:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:List_of_German_cognates_with_English

Zur Einengung der Fragestellung solltest du vielleicht noch definieren, ob es einen Punkt in der Sprachgeschichte des Englischen gibt, bis zu dem die Wörter auf jeden Fall noch in Verwendung gewesen sein müssen. Deine Beispiele haben alle noch attestierte (regelmäßige) Verwendung bis ins Frühneuenglische (ca. 1500-1700). Ist das nur der Beispielauswahl geschuldet, oder interessieren dich auch Wörter, die schon im Mittelenglischen (ca. 1150-1500) oder sogar Altenglischen (ca. 450-1150) aufgegeben wurden?

Und ist für dich die Bedeutungsgleichheit ein relevantes Kriterium? *clean* und *klein* z.B. sind zwar etymologisch verwandt und gehen auf die selbe germanische Wurzel zurück, aber während das Englische die ursprüngliche Bedeutung weitgehend behalten hat, hat im Deutschen eine Bedeutungsänderung stattgefunden (ausführliche Besprechung hier: http://blog.oup.com/2016/08/etymology-word-clean/).

Comment: Die Frage ist anders als sie von Ihnen formuliert wird. Sie bezieht sich auf Wörterfamilien, die sowohl auf Englisch als auch auf Deutsch heutzutage verwendet werden, welche, insoweit sie einen gemeinsamen Ursprung haben, "dieselben" sind, aber nicht mehr produktiv, oder weniger produktiv, in einer oder der anderen Sprache sind. D.h. neue Wörter werden weniger oft aus ihnen in einer oder der anderen Sprache erzeugt, mit dem Effekt, dass ihren gemeinsamen Ursprung schwerer zu erkennen ist, genau deswegen, dass sie mehr oder weniger produktiv in einer der Sprachen verwendet werden.

Comment: Impulsiv denke ich, dass ich womöglich Beispiele mit immer noch ähnlichen Bedeutungen bevorzugen würde, aber andererseits sehe ich auch keinen guten Grund, andere Beispiele auszuschließen, soweit den Ursprung und die Wirklichkeit der Bedeutungsänderung gut dokumentiert und bewiesen sind.

Comment: Zur Klarstellung würde ich empfehlen, das wichtige Schlüsselwort "produktiv" in die Frage mit aufzunehmen. Aktuell steht nur im Fragentitel "aktiv" und im Fragentext "bis heute verwendet".

Comment: Das stimmt. Eigentlich wollte ich eher "forlorn" und "verlieren" vergleichen (d.h. anstatt "*forlese*" und "verlieren"), aber während ich gerade den Text neu lese, bin ich mit Ihnen einverstanden, dass diese Ideen waren überhaupt nicht klar, d.h. ich kommunizierte die Idee in meinem Kopf offenbar weder deutlich noch richtig. Es tut mir Leid. Bitte geben Sie mir Bescheid, falls meine neue Redaktionen der Klarstellung nicht genug dienen.

Answer (score 1):

Vergleiche im plattdeutschen: "she is too late" / "he is too late" heisst im plattdeutschen "Se is to late" bzw "He is to late".